# Suppress "Alarm clock: 14" from ping

Tags: bash, signals, ping

I've made a simple script for rebooting my router and afterwards showing a progress bar until my computer has an internet connection again.

When running the script I get the following output:

```
The router is now rebooting...
############################################bin/reboot_router: line 48:  4758 Alarm clock: 14         ping -Q -c 1 -t 1 google.com >&/dev/null
#bin/reboot_router: line 48:  4761 Alarm clock: 14         ping -Q -c 1 -t 1 google.com >&/dev/null
#bin/reboot_router: line 48:  4763 Alarm clock: 14         ping -Q -c 1 -t 1 google.com >&/dev/null
#####bin/reboot_router: line 48:  4773 Alarm clock: 14         ping -Q -c 1 -t 1 google.com >&/dev/null
#bin/reboot_router: line 48:  4775 Alarm clock: 14         ping -Q -c 1 -t 1 google.com >&/dev/null
##bin/reboot_router: line 48:  4777 Alarm clock: 14         ping -Q -c 1 -t 1 google.com >&/dev/null
#
```

I want to suppress the `Alarm clock: 14` thing from appearing, so the output becomes:

```
The router is now rebooting...
#######################################################
```

The relevant part of the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

COLUMNS=$(tput cols)

# Reboot router code here

echo 'The router is now rebooting...'

min_time=60
max_time=120
start_time=$SECONDS
time=0
progress=0

until [[ $min_time -lt $time ]] && ping -Q -c 1 -t 1 google.com &> /dev/null; do
    let time=SECONDS-start_time
    let new_progress=COLUMNS*time/max_time
    let diff=new_progress-progress
    let progress=new_progress
    for((i=0; i<diff; i++)); do
        echo -n '#'
    done
    sleep 1
done

echo
```

Comment: You have an error in your `ping` command (try running it without redirecting output), the `-Q` flag needs a value.

Comment: @terdon Nope. My version of `ping` doesn't need/support an argument for `-Q`. It works fine without an argument and fails with an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull the `ping` out into it's own function and do whatever you want in there with the results. At the end return a 0 or 1 depending on the status internally in the function.

```
ping_func(){
    results=$(ping -c 1 -t 1 google.com &> /dev/null)
    return $?
}

until [[ $min_time -lt $time ]] && ping_func; do
    let time=SECONDS-start_time
    let new_progress=COLUMNS*time/max_time
    let diff=new_progress-progress
    let progress=new_progress
    for((i=0; i<diff; i++)); do
        echo -n '#'
    done
    sleep 1
done

echo
```

Alternatively you can use a more elaborate `case/switch` within the function if you need to act differently when getting different statuses from the `ping`.

```
case "$status" in
    1) return 0 ## success   ;;
    0) return 1 ## fail      ;;
    *) ### do something else ;;
esac
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as I can't extract the exit code from `ping` then.

Comment: @Tyilo - see updates

Comment: that doesn't work either as: 1) `grep` will wait for a full line, however the script outputs `#` on at a time and I want to see them 2) It would also remove the whole line including the previous `#` 3) I think `ping` does something like `echo foobar > /dev/tty`, which can't be blocked like that.

Comment: @Tyilo - someone mentioned there was a typo in your `ping` command in the chatroom. `-Q` needs an arg. `ping -Q <some num> -c 1 -t 1 google.com`.

Comment: @Tyilo - 3rd time a charm?

Comment: My version of `ping` doesn't need/support an argument for `-Q`. Also how do you filter out the `Alarm clock` in this version?

Comment: @Tyilo - see updates.

Comment: Works with my suggested edit. You only check for status code == `1`, when it is `68` sometimes...

Comment: @Tyilo - yes you can just return the status too. I wasn't sure what status was getting returned from ping, I showed 0 and 1 for examples. If there are a variety of statuses then just add either a case/switch statement for each of them or if/elsif blocks.

Comment: I've tried this solution but am still getting the message, `line 26: 54181 Alarm clock: 14 […]` using ping on OS X 10.9. Any suggestions? Specifically, I'm calling like, `(ping -Q -W 3000 -t 3 -i .1 google.com &>/dev/null) &>/dev/null
return $?;`

Comment: @quinn - ask that as a new question and reference this question in it.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that your ping command contains `-t 1` to tell ping to give up after 1 second. This is causing a `SIGALRM` signal that ping is failing to trap internally. (This is arguably a ping bug but that's academic). The bash shell reports this as `Alarm clock: 14` and aborts the process with an exit status of `142` ; 128 (which is the "I caught a signal" flag) + 14 (the SIGALRM id).

There are two ways to deal with this:

1) Remove the `-t 1` so that the SIGALRM is not generated. Instead, ping will time out in (in my experience) 5 seconds, and give a different error status than you're currently seeing; probably 68 if the specified host can't be reached.  In this case you might also want to add "-o" to your ping so that it will terminate as soon as the host does become reachable.

2) Execute `trap - SIGALRM` just before your ping command, to tell the shell to ignore the signal. The 1-second timeout will still happen, and the exit status will still be `142`. At least, that's what it did on the iMac running Yosemite (10.10.5) on which I tried it.